# What is the motherboard of HP pavilion dv7-2185DX?

Tags: motherboard, hp-pavilion, specifications

I [found everything but](http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/hp-pavilion-dv7-2185dx/4507-3121_7-33695858.html) the motherboard it uses.

Which one is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, looking at the product spec for the [HP Pavilion dv7-2185dx](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?docname=c01753029&tmp_task=prodinfoCategory&lc=en&dlc=en&cc=us&lang=en&product=3979540) on the HP site there is no mention of the motherboard, but the computer's product number is given as `NV023UA#ABA`.

So, if we take that product number to the [HP PartsSurfer](http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?searchText=NV023UA#ABA) we find that the main board is only listed as a `System board (motherboard) - UMA architecture`, which isn't really helpful and is a very strong indication it is customised and/or proprietary to HP, but we can see that the motherboards HP Part number is [`516294-001`](http://partsurfer.hp.com/Search.aspx?SearchText=516294-001).

This still isn't really helpful in general; probably the only thing it really helps with is if you happen to need a replacement for the motherboard, but such is the nature of the custom/proprietary motherboards used in laptops / netbooks / etc.

Answer (score 2):

http://reviews.cnet.com/laptops/hp-pavilion-dv7-2185dx/4505-3121_7-33695858.html#reviewPage1

> Mobile Intel PM45 Express Chipset

http://majorgeeks.com/download4181.html

It seems that it is a PM45 Express chipset, Motherboard can be custom but it is the chipset which is important - so you download drivers accordingly.

the utility "Everest" can be useful in getting the MOBO / Chipset details.
Hope that helps

PM45 Express Chipset Overview
http://www.intel.com/products/notebook/chipsets/pm45/pm45-overview.htm

Answer (score 0):

It, like pretty much all laptop motherboards, is completely custom.

Answer (score 0):

I happen to have a HP DV7, and this is what `dmidecode` says:

```
Handle 0x0002, DMI type 2, 16 bytes
Base Board Information
    Manufacturer: Compal
    Product Name: 30F4
    Version: 99.55
    Serial Number: CND83522TN
    Asset Tag: Base Board Asset Tag
    Features:
        Board is a hosting board
        Board is replaceable
    Location In Chassis: Base Board Chassis Location
    Chassis Handle: 0x0003
    Type: Motherboard
    Contained Object Handles: 0
```

And just for completion, here's the info about the product:

```
Handle 0x0001, DMI type 1, 27 bytes
System Information
    Manufacturer: Hewlett-Packard
    Product Name: HP Pavilion dv7 Notebook PC
    Version: F.0A
    Serial Number: CND83522TN
    UUID: 03C6105D-6F98-11DD-B035-001EECA609D4
    Wake-up Type: Power Switch
    SKU Number: FP903EA#ABD
    Family: 103C_5335KV
```

[Compal](http://www.compal.com/) is a Taiwanese company (making everything), the chassis is also made by Compal.